# Can we do non API testing with Karate framework? If yes how?

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, tdd, karate

I'm trying to migrate from Cucumber to Karate framework from our backend application (not API related)
But all the documents of karate I search in the internet are only having API related karate tests.
Can we test non API related back end applications using Karate framework ?
I'm trying to make non IT folks write their own test cases (so wanted to see if karate can do it ) .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you are able to write some Java "glue" code. Note that the glue code is far simpler than Cucumber, and it is code you need to write only once. Typically, enterprises have a central team write the glue code you need (e.g. to connect to a database or some custom protocol you have such as gRPC). Once that glue code is in place, you just focus on writing business-logic focused tests in Gherkin.

Refer this for an extreme example: https://twitter.com/getkarate/status/1417023536082812935

Search for Java interop and you would find more Karate examples for this kind of stuff.